Can't deploy firebase functions due to missing package
I'm trying to deploy my firebase functions but I get an error that I can't fix.
This is my package.json in the root directory:
{
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node lib/index.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "name": "tureeng-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "url..."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "url..."
  },
  "homepage": "url...",
  "dependencies": {
    "@genkit-ai/ai": "0.5.10",
    "@genkit-ai/core": "^0.5.7",
    "@genkit-ai/dotprompt": "^0.5.7",
    "@genkit-ai/firebase": "^0.5.7",
    "@genkit-ai/flow": "^0.5.7",
    "@genkit-ai/googleai": "^0.5.7",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.2.0",
    "json-schema": "^0.4.0",
    "node-telegram-bot-api": "^0.65.1",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/json-schema": "^7.0.15",
    "typegram": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3"
  }
}

And this is the package.json in the functions directory:
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "firebase-admin": "12.3.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^5.0.1",
    "json-schema": "^0.4.0",
    "node-telegram-bot-api": "^0.66.0",
    "telegraf": "github:telegraf/telegraf",
    "typegram": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/json-schema": "^7.0.15",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "private": true
}


When I run the following command:
firebase deploy --only functions

I get this error:
i  functions: updating Node.js 20 (1st Gen) function app(us-central1)...
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@genkit-ai/ai'
Require stack:
- /workspace/lib/models/GenKitStrategy.js
- /workspace/lib/endpoints/sendMessageFakeAI.js
- /workspace/lib/index.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/lib/models/GenKitStrategy.js:16:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
Could not load the function, shutting down.. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        app(us-central1)

So apparently the genkit-ai module cannot be found even though it's included in the package.json file. What am I missing?
I've included the missing module (genkit-ai) but it is still not working

I doubt that the modules declared in your root package will be seen by the code in the functions package.  The functions package has to stand alone as an independently deployable unit.  That might explain the error message you're seeing.

To rephrase what Doug is saying, your ./functions/package.json needs the @genkit-ai/ai dependency (and other relevant modules) added to it.

Ok that sounds good, today I will try to move those dependencies inside the functions folder and see if that fixes the problem. Thanks
